# IP Spoofing in HTTP Request?

Tags: ip, httprequest, spoofing

I know someone that is able to take a list of emails + ip addresses and
subscribe each email to an autoresponder (GetResponse / Aweber).
But the amazing thing is that he can do it with the ip address that's provided
in the list.

So if he has an email xxx@abc.com and IP 185.252.123.321
he's able so subscribe this email to the autoresponder but
if you enter into the autoresponder account and look on the
lead record, you'll see 185.252.123.321 in the IP address field
and not the real IP address that the request sent from.

Does someone have any idea how could he do it?

Answer (score 0):

If the software is using the [X-Originating-IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Originating-IP) mail header to determine the IP address of the email, then this can be easily spoofed.

`X-Originating-IP: 185.252.123.321`

It is trivial to set this header from a mail client that allows customer headers to be set or if the person is connecting to an [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) server directly and setting it themselves. You may find [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/6942/60867) relevant too.

Comment: I think I didn't explain very well.

What his application does is to send an http post request (from fake IP address) to https://some_auto_responder.com (like aweber,getresponse, etc...) with the email address he want to subscribe to his email list and the autoresponder accept the IP as a real IP.

Maybe he has a proxy in the middle that change the raw packet (change the source ip) and the proxy send the packet to its destination (to the autoresponder).

Could it be the case? is it possible?

Comment: Only if the IP of the proxy is the address you want to use. [IP spoofing is not possible over the public internet](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/37481/8340).